# Asynchronous query execution with psycopg2 and Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have a Redshift cluster and use psycopg2 library with Lambda to call stored procedures in Redshift.

I have two stored procedures and use

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("call stored_procedure_1()")
```

to run the procedure in Redshift.

I believe this is a synchronous operation?

I would like to call both the stored procedures asynchronously, without having to wait for one to complete before calling the other.

Is it possible to do this with psycopg on Redshift?

Thank you.